# how to identify/detech circular objects in java script?

Tags: javascript, object, circular-reference, stringify

How to identify/detect the circular object types in java script ?

Example for circular objects:

```
const obj = {    
  name: "loopObj"
};
    
const loopObj = {    
  obj    
};

obj.loopObj = loopObj;
```

If we try to stringify the circular object using JSON.stringify(obj), it will throw an error as shown below

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON  at JSON.stringify
> ()

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to find the circular objects? Or do you want to stringify the object?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

Here is a simple function to detect circular object using `try` and `catch`

```js
function isCircular (d) {
  try {JSON.stringify(d)}
  catch (e) {return true}
  return false
}
```

### Solution 2

[Crockford's JSON implementation](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/cycle.js) does just that. It looks like it just keeps a list while traversing the object graph.